# Динамический массив структур с вложенным динамическим массивом

Tags: c, память, malloc

Всем привет.

Я пытаюсь сделать динамический массив меню из такой структуры:

```
typedef struct menu menu_s;
typedef struct menu{
    int size;
    char top_text[16];
    char bottom_text[16];
    menu_s* subMenus;
    void (*action)(void);
}menu_s;
static menu_s *menus;
```

Т.е. массив `menus` содержит пункты основного меню, а `subMenus` содержит подпункты какого-то пункта меню, `size` хранит количество этих подменю. Как мы понимаем, количество подпунктов может быть разным.

Функции, которыми я выделяю память:

```
static int menusCount = 0;

void createMenusItem(char *top_text, char *bottom_text)
{
    menus = (menu_s*)realloc(menus, (++menusCount)*sizeof(menu_s));
    memcpy(menus[menusCount-1].top_text, top_text, 16);
    memcpy(menus[menusCount-1].bottom_text, bottom_text, 16);
    menus[menusCount-1].size = 0;
}

void createSubItem(int id, char *top_text, char *bottom_text)
{
    if (id < menusCount){
        menus[id].subMenus = (menu_s*)realloc(menus[id].subMenus, (++menus[id].size)*sizeof(menu_s));
        menus[id].subMenus[menus[id].size-1].size = 0;
        memcpy(menus[id].subMenus[menus[id].size-1].top_text, top_text, 16);
        memcpy(menus[id].subMenus[menus[id].size-1].bottom_text, bottom_text, 16);
    }
}

void clearMenus(void)
{
    free(menus);
}
```

Если просто создавать пункты основного меню, все ОК, но если захотим создать где-то подменю, а затем создать еще один основной пункт меню, программа виснет. Т.е. как-то так:

```
createMenusItem("qw", "as");
createMenusItem("df", "ewr");
createMenusItem("ghj", "34");
createSubItem(2, "ghj", "34");
createMenusItem("324", "34"); //тут упадем на попытке выполнить realloc
```

Собственно, вопрос в том, как правильно "растолкать" память так, чтобы все были довольны. Пока не могу сообразить

Comment: Первый typedef лишний, вероятно в realloc попадает неинициализированная переменная, предварительно присвойте ей NULL при инициализации. memset может помочь :) в createMenusItem, или просто в ручную.

Comment: @NewView Пишу этот код под микроконтроллер в Atmel Studio. Сейчас решил запустить на плюсах в QtCreator, выполнилось без проблем, даже все тексты (`top_text`, `bottom_text`) в консольку вывелись. Дернул черт в дебаггере прогнать, так сразу `Segmentation fault` прилетел вот здесь: `menus[id].subMenus[menus[id].size-1].size = 0;`

Comment: Так я и говорю, что переменная  subMenus в структуре   не определена, NULL ей присвойте при инициализации нового объекта. realloc там в шоке наверное :)

Comment: @NewView Да уж, `realloc` настрадался) как-то не учел момент с этим указателем. По идее указатель `menus` тоже не инициализирован, но он автоматом занулился, т.к. глобальный, вот и ввел меня в заблуждение. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции не инициализирована переменная `menu_s* subMenus;` с `NULL`.

```
void createMenusItem(char *top_text, char *bottom_text){
    menus = (menu_s*)realloc(menus, (++menusCount)*sizeof(menu_s));
    memcpy(menus[menusCount-1].top_text, top_text, 16);
    memcpy(menus[menusCount-1].bottom_text, bottom_text, 16);
    menus[menusCount-1].size = 0;}
```

Если в этой переменной находится мусор, то `realloc` от мусора падает.

```
void createSubItem(int id, char *top_text, char *bottom_text){
    if (id < menusCount){
        menus[id].subMenus = (menu_s*)realloc(menus[id].subMenus, (++menus[id].size)*sizeof(menu_s));
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Упустил этот момент..